# How to get the x and y axis distributions evenly in jqplot?

Tags: jqplot

I have a jqplot with varying data points, so x and y axis max values changes constantly. Because of this x and y axes are not distributing equally. How can make the distribution even?

[image: jqplot with x/y axis ditribution]

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by specifying [tickInterval](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.tickInterval).